# Grey circles in the background in photos

Tags: lens, artifacts, backlight

All my photos contain grey circles which is especially noticable  on light background (e.g. sky). I don't know what is the name of this specific artefact and what is connected to (lens? camera?). So far I am fighting against it  by healing tool in Lightroom, but would like to know more about this issue.

Photo attached.

Camera: Nikon Z5
Lens: Nikkor Z 25-78mm f/2.8

[image]

Comment: For me looks like dust spots on sensor.

Comment: or spots on especially the rear element of your lens....

Comment: No matter how much I clean, these circles are still there.

Comment: @inna, did you clean the sensor of the camera?

Comment: Thanks guys, Romeo, twalberg, seems that indeed from the rear element of lens or the camera sensor itself. Just cleaned and it worked 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause is dust on your sensor or less probable on the rear element of the lens.

You can visually inspect the sensor by removing the lens and using a good light to see if there is dust. If yes, hold your camera with sensor downwards and use a rocket blower to blow the dust out.

If that is not sufficient, you can also use a speck-grabber (some sort of plastic stick with a sticky jelly at the end) or use a wet cleaning kit or find a dealer that offers sensor cleaning.

In my experience, sensor cleaning is no magic and can easily done at home.

Afterwards take a photograph of a bright even colored surface (cloudless sky works, too) with the aperture closed. You should now have no specks left in the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as soon as I had discovered that it's from sensor, I have bought a sensor cleaning kit, and it seems it helped, at least reduced the spots drastically. There is still a couple of dust left but I am afraid to clean my lens that much

Answer (score -3):

Sorry to report -- I think this is caused by gouges on the front surface of your camera lens. If not gouges, then smudges, perhaps oil spots. Try cleaning with alcohol mixed 50:50 with water.